# Good approach to develop android Tablet app

Tags: android

I have got a project that implement tablet version of an app. this app has only portrait mode without landscape mode support. so my approach would be implementation for both in tablet.

However, you guys all know that android has different type of devices and android version. how to make sure that my tablet app will work for every tablet devices. Also UI, what is the best practice to do in tablet? how can I make sure my app layout is fit in all devices? What kind of UI framework would be useful for developing android tablet?

Comment: Use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Android documentation covers these topics, [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html) , [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use fragments. So your app could look like this:

[image]

- Create a layout, one for a handset and one for a tablet.

**layout/main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/handset"
[...]
>
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout-large/sw400dp:**

```
<LinearLayout 
  [...]
  >

    <fragment android:name="com.bla.bla.FirstFragment"
              android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
              [...]
              />

     <fragment android:name="com.bla.bla.SecondFragment"
              android:id="@+id/second_fragment"
              [...]
              />

</LinearLayout>
```

- Now check for this in your FragmentActivity:

---

```
if (findViewById(R.id.handset) != null) {
    // it's a handset device and you can add a Fragment to this View
    }

 FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.handset, firstFragment).commit();
```

- if `R.id.handset` returns null then it's a tablet, in this case the statically added Fragments will be handled by their Fragments class.